# JPA 2.1 says attribute "indexes is undefined"

Tags: java, jpa, indexing, undefined, wildfly

im currently developing a web-app using Wildfly 8.0.0 with Hibernate JPA 2.1.
My problem is, that i can't annotate a ManyToOne with its indexes.

```
import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import de.sessions.benutzerverwaltung.domain.Benutzer;

@Entity
@Table(indexes = { @Index(columnList = "user_fk"), @Index(columnList = "session_fk") })
@Cacheable
public class Comment implements Serializable{
...
```

Eclipse says that "The attribute indexes is undefined for the annotation type Table" 
In another Project it works perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: My error displaying this seems to be eclipse is classloading JPA2.0 instead of 2.1 - worth checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by deleting the class and creating it new (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>) and the problem was gone. Eclipse....